# SQL Server 2008: Restrict column value with respect to another column value

Tags: sql-server-2008, constraints, check-constraints

I have a table with 2 columns

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
  x int
  y char(1)
)
```

I would like to enforce constraint on y with respect to the value of x.

For example, when x = 5 I want to have y='a', when x = 12 y = 'b' and so on.
Is it possible to do in SQL Server 2008? Something like

```
case when x = 5 then y='a' end
```

The latter statement does not work, therefore, I am asking for analog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
  x int not null,
  y char(1) not null,
  constraint CK_mytable_myrules CHECK (
    1 = CASE
          WHEN x=5 AND y='a' THEN 1
          WHEN x=12 AND y='b' THEN 1
        /* More rules here */
          ELSE 0 END
)
```

A CASE *expression* always has to return a *value*. Booleans are not part of SQL.

---

Or, if the general rule is "if we haven't matched any of these rules, let it through", then you have two choices - nested CASEs, or "fallback" rules (my own, just invented term):

nested CASEs:

```
    1 = CASE
          WHEN x=5 THEN
             CASE WHEN y='a' THEN 1
                  ELSE 0 END
          WHEN x=12 THEN
             CASE WHEN y='b' THEN 1
                  ELSE 0 END
        /* More rules here */
          ELSE 1 END
```

or the other way:

```
    1 = CASE
          WHEN x=5 AND y='a' THEN 1
          WHEN x=5 THEN 0
          WHEN x=12 AND y='b' THEN 1
          WHEN x=12 THEN 0
        /* More rules here */
          ELSE 1 END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the expression to:

```
( x = 5 AND y = 'a' ) OR ( x = 12 AND y = 'b' )
```

Add more rules if you like...

Add the constraint to your table with this SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.myTable WITH NOCHECK  
      ADD  CONSTRAINT CK_myTable
      CHECK  (( x = 5 AND y = 'a' ) OR ( x = 12 AND y = 'b' ));
```

Check this reference for more examples:

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3811831/Using-Check-Constraints-to-Validate-Data-in-SQL-Server.htm

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set up such constraints. Cf. [link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258.aspx) 
You need to define a suitable UDF.

Ah there seem to be other possibilities too.